# Using predict on new text with kmeans (sklearn)?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, nlp, k-means

I have a **very small**  list of **short strings** which I want to (1) cluster and (2) use that model to predict which cluster a new string belongs to.

Running the first part works fine, getting a prediction for the new string does not.

### First Part

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

# List of 
documents_lst = ['a small, narrow river',
                'a continuous flow of liquid, air, or gas',
                'a continuous flow of data or instructions, typically one having a constant or predictable rate.',
                'a group in which schoolchildren of the same age and ability are taught',
                '(of liquid, air, gas, etc.) run or flow in a continuous current in a specified direction',
                'transmit or receive (data, especially video and audio material) over the Internet as a steady, continuous flow.',
                'put (schoolchildren) in groups of the same age and ability to be taught together',
                'a natural body of running water flowing on or under the earth']


# 1. Vectorize the text
tfidf_vectorizer  = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english')
tfidf_matrix = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(documents_lst)
print('tfidf_matrix.shape: ', tfidf_matrix.shape)

# 2. Get the number of clusters to make .. (find a better way than random)
num_clusters = 3

# 3. Cluster the defintions
km = KMeans(n_clusters=num_clusters, init='k-means++').fit(tfidf_matrix)

clusters = km.labels_.tolist()

print(clusters)
```

Which returns:

```
tfidf_matrix.shape:  (8, 39)
[0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 0]
```

### Second Part

The failing part:

```
predict_doc = ['A stream is a body of water with a current, confined within a bed and banks.']

tfidf_vectorizer  = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english')
tfidf_matrix = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(predict_doc)
print('tfidf_matrix.shape: ', tfidf_matrix.shape)

km.predict(tfidf_matrix)
```

#### The error:

```
ValueError: Incorrect number of features. Got 7 features, expected 39
```

FWIW: I somewhat understand that the training and predict have a different amount of features after vectorizing ...

I am open to any solution including changing from kmeans to an algorithm more suitable for short text clustering.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are training a new tfidfvectorizer for prediction task. So it generates a different set of features. You should use original tfidf_vectorizer

Comment: @VivekKumar Of course :). Duh. That makes sense.  [http://stackoverflow.com/a/26943563/6041010]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For completeness I will answer my own question with an answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26943563/6041010) , that doesn't answer that question.  But answers mine

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

list1 = ["My name is xyz", "My name is pqr", "I work in abc"]
list2 = ["My name is xyz", "I work in abc"]

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(min_df = 0, max_df=0.5, stop_words = "english", charset_error = "ignore", ngram_range = (1,3))
vec = vectorizer.fit(list1)   # train vec using list1
vectorized = vec.transform(list1)   # transform list1 using vec

km = KMeans(n_clusters=2, init='k-means++', n_init=10, max_iter=1000, tol=0.0001, precompute_distances=True, verbose=0, random_state=None, n_jobs=1)

km.fit(vectorized)
list2Vec = vec.transform(list2)  # transform list2 using vec
km.predict(list2Vec)
```

The credit goes to @IrshadBhat