# ValueError while predicting a document in a scikit-learn k-means cluster

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means, pca

I am trying to predict a cluster for a bunch of test documents in a trained k-means model using scikit-learn.

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english')
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(train_documents)
k = 10
model = KMeans(n_clusters=k, init='k-means++', max_iter=100, n_init=1)
model.fit(X)
```

The model is generated without any problem with 10 clusters. But when I try to predict a list of documents, I get an error.

```
predicted_cluster = model.predict(test_documents)
```

Error message:

**ValueError: could not convert string to float...**

Do I need to use PCA to reduce the number of features, or do I need to do preprocessing for the text document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to transform the `test_documents` the same way in which train was transformed.

```
X_test = vectorizer.transform(test_documents)
predicted_cluster = model.predict(X_test)
```

Make sure you only call `transform` on the test documents and use the same `vectorizer` object which was used for `fit()` or `fit_transform()` on train documents.

Comment: Or rather X_test = vectorizer.transform(test_documents)

Comment: @pgrenholm yes. Corrected. Thanks. Even though I specifically stated not to do that, it seems  that I myself made that mistake

Comment: Yes. It worked for me. Thanks a lot. I got an error like: The incorrect number of features but the following post came to the rescue for that.

http://stackoverflow.com/a/26943563/1269131

Comment: @SiMemon Ok. I thought that it will be understood because I used the same name in my code. But I should have explicitly mentioned about using the same object.